# Why does this picture spill too far to the right?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a few pictures where the box around them is too big. The code below is an example. In this case the figure goes too far to the right. Can anyone help me get these under control?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\tcbox{
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (F1) at (0,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F1};
\node (B1) at (0,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B1};
\node (B2) at (2.5,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B2};
\node (F2) at (2.5,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F2};
\node (F3) at (2.5,-2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {F3};
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {2} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {3} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[above left] {6} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {1} (F2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[right] {1} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F3) -- node[right] {1} (F2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (F1) at (0,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F1};
\node (B1) at (0,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B1};
\node (B2) at (2.5,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B2};
\node (F2) at (2.5,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F2};
\node (F3) at (2.5,-2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {F3};
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {2} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {7} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[above left] {6} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {1} (F2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[right] {3} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F3) -- node[right] {1} (F2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}%
}
\end{centering}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The diagrams or the box? You have two minipages each with width `0.5\textwidth`, so naturally the `\tcbox` becomes wider than `\textwidth` in total.

Comment: Note that `\tcbox{` followed by a line break can add a space which moves the content to the right. TeX does take line breaks as spaces. To avoid this add a `%` to ignore the line break: `\tcbox{%`.

Comment: If you want to scale and center boxed content check out the `adjustbox` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably this is what you were after?

[image: output of code]

The extra space in the box in your case came from the `minipage` environments, that were wider than the `tikzpicture`s, and thus created a lot of extra space. But from what you show in your code, there is no reason to use minipages here, so I'd just remove them. You can add some horizontal space between the diagrams with `\hspace`, if needed.

Note also that `centering` is not actually an environment, it is a macro that should be used as `\centering`, which affects the text that follows it in the same group. There is an environment called `center`, but that adds some vertical space, and is usually not recommended inside a `figure`, cf. [Should I use center or centering for figures and tables?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables/2652#2652)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tcbox{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (F1) at (0,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F1};
\node (B1) at (0,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B1};
\node (B2) at (2.5,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B2};
\node (F2) at (2.5,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F2};
\node (F3) at (2.5,-2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {F3};
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {2} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {3} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[above left] {6} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {1} (F2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[right] {1} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F3) -- node[right] {1} (F2);
\end{tikzpicture}\hspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (F1) at (0,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F1};
\node (B1) at (0,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B1};
\node (B2) at (2.5,2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {B2};
\node (F2) at (2.5,0) [draw, shape=circle] {F2};
\node (F3) at (2.5,-2.5) [draw, shape=circle] {F3};
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {2} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {7} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[above left] {6} (B1);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F1) -- node[below left] {1} (F2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F2) -- node[right] {3} (B2);
\draw [-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (F3) -- node[right] {1} (F2);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```